# AddDirectoryDll not accepting full path

Tags: c, dll

I'm trying to use AddDllDirectory to add the directory of a dir, relative to a dll, with some other dll I want to use in my application.

I obtain the full path to the current dll using `GetModuleHandleEx`, then I dissect that full path using `_splitpath`, then rebuild the path without the filename and extension using `_makepath`.

I then transform the resulting char to wchar_t, and pass it on to `AddDllDirectory` like this:

```
cookie = AddDllDirectory(dlldir);
        
if (cookie == 0) {
    printf("\nDir load failed\n");
}
else {
    printf("Dir load success\n");
}
```

So I know that adding the dir failed.

What could be the problem?
This is how I transform the char string to wchar_t, adding double backslashes in the proccess:

```
wchar_t dlldir[100];

int j = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 83; i++) //83 is the length of the string before adding double backslashes
{
    dlldir[i + j] = dlldir_char[i];

    if (dlldir_char[i] == '\\'){
        dlldir[i + ++j] = dlldir_char[i];
    }
}
```

This is how dlldir looks like, by the way:

```
C:\\path\\to\\where\\the\first\\dll\\is\\
```

Comment: Why the weird special treatment for the backslash character in your transformation?

Comment: I was unsure if the reason the dir loading was failing was that the string required escape characters

Comment: The actual string doesn't have any escape characters - a backslash is a single `char` or a single `wchar_t`. The escape sequence is used only in literal representations in your code. The string shown in your last snippet is not a valid directory path.

Comment: Escape sequences are just for the compiler.